# XML Schema: Difference between using <xs:all> and not when minOccurs="0"

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation

What is the difference between this (taken from w3schools.com reference for `<xs:all>`):

```
<xs:element name="person">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:all>
      <xs:element name="firstname" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="lastname" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:all>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

And this:

```
<xs:element name="person">
  <xs:complexType>
      <xs:element name="firstname" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="lastname" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Notice each child element contains `minOccurs="0"`, and notice the lack of the `<xs:all>` tag in the second example.

As I understand it, if the child elements didn't specify `minOccurs="0"`, then `<xs:all>` makes it so the entire group can not appear at all. Whereas not using `<xs:all>` means all child elements have to appear once, because the default value for `minOccurs` and `maxOccurs` in an element is 1.

But, when you do specify `minOccurs="0"` on all the child elements, wouldn't both examples be the same constraint? Don't both mean each element can either appear once or not appear?

I'm not seeing much use for the `<xs:all>` element. Maybe you can tell me where it is useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your second example is not a valid XSD because `xs:element` cannot appear as a child of `xs:complexType`.  Let's assume that your second example was actually

```
<xs:element name="person">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="firstname" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="lastname" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Then, we can explain when to use which as follows:

- Use `xs:sequence` when **element ordering** is ***significant***.
- Use `xs:all` when element ordering is ***insignificant***.

In both cases, `minOccurs="0"` means that the associated element is optional.

So, in your (fixed) case, your `xs:all` example would allow `firstname` and `lastname` to appear as children on `person` in any order; your `xs:sequence` example would constrain `firstname` to appear *before* `lastname` as children of `person`.

Comment: Yep, that makes more sense now. The w3schools.com tutorial doesn't really go over the fact that `xs:element` has to be a child of one of the order indicators or the group indicator. I'm new to this. Thanks!